# How to count the number of times a loop ran and wasn't skipped?

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to run (something similar) and figure how many times the loop actually ran

```yaml
- name: this step
  debug:
    msg: "working on {{ item.name }}"
  when: not item.skip
  with_list: 
    - {name: t1, skip: True}
    - {name: t2, skip: False}
    - {name: t3, skip: False}
    - {name: t4, skip: False}
    - {name: t5, skip: True}
```

In this simplified version, I want to get 3

```yaml
  register: somedata

- debug:
    msg: "{{ somedata.results | length }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the registered variable *loop_results*, count how many items were skipped

```yaml
    skip: "{{ loop_results.results |
              json_query('[?skipped]') |
              length }}"
```

Count the number of times a loop ran

```yaml
    run: "{{ loop_results.results|length - skip|int }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    skip: "{{ loop_results.results |
              json_query('[?skipped]') |
              length }}"
    run: "{{ loop_results.results|length - skip|int }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "working on {{ item.name }}"
      loop:
        - {name: t1, skip: True}
        - {name: t2, skip: False}
        - {name: t3, skip: False}
        - {name: t4, skip: False}
        - {name: t5, skip: True}
      register: loop_results
      when: not item.skip

    - debug:
        var: loop_results
    - debug:
        var: skip
    - debug:
        var: run
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  skip: '2'
  run: '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be this:

```yaml
- name: this step
  debug:
    msg: "working on {{ item.name }}"
  when: "not item.skip"
  with_items:
    - { name: t1, skip: True }
    - { name: t2, skip: False }
    - { name: t3, skip: False }
    - { name: t4, skip: False }
    - { name: t5, skip: True }
  register: loop_results

- name: print number of iterations
  debug:
    msg: "{{ loop_results.results | length }}"
```

Comment: I am still getting 5